# How to adjust border radius to match parent border radius

Tags: html, css, border-radius

I want to have a text box with a line on the left side for design purpouses. The box has a border radius oh 10px. The problem is that the line is too thick if I make it 10px wide. So I made it 5px and tried to adjust the horizontal and vertical radiuses separately to make it match the border of the box. I have tried for ages and I just cant get it right. Here's my best attempt:

[image]

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 50, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 3px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px / 10px 0 0 10px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Make me beautiful!</p>
</div>
```

Is it even possible to make this work and how?

Edit: I'm using the same variable for the background color of the line and the box. Then I'm applying a filter to the line to make it darker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only for decoration, use a gradient:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.5) 0 0) /* color */
     left / 5px 100% no-repeat, /* position / width height */
   rgba(0, 255, 50, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Make me beautiful!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually there is a little bit of a problem with this - I am using the same color for the line and the box and then applying a filter to the line. That way I can quickly switch which variable I am using for the color and I don't have to adjust anything. Any way to add that filter in here?

Comment: Please explain a little more. What do you mean by "switch which variable I am using for the color"? What _is_ the filter? What about replacing `rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.5)` with a CSS var?

Comment: @UnityGames000 we always ask people to provide complete clear question with all the requirements to get accurate answers. There is problem with my answer but you have to edit your question to include all the details

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I have both the line and the box color set to a variable. I want to be able to change the variable and have both elements still look good with the line being just a bit darker. So I'm using a brightness filter.